# Creating custom iterating "each" function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct my own object and creating functions for it. I have the following object which takes the letters out of a string:

```
var Letters = function( word ) {
    this.letters = word.split('');
    this.length = this.letters.length;
    return this;
};
```

Then I create a function that allows to add letters/string to a instance of the *Letters* object:

```
Letters.prototype.addLetter = function(toAdd) {
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        this.letters[i] += toAdd;
    }
    return this;
};
```

My problem is that when I try to create a custom *each* function, which iterates through an instance of the *Letters* object, and I apply the method *addLetter* to the current iteration of the instance of *Letter*, I get an error message that says that the current iteration does not have the method *addLetter*.

This is what I have written so far:

```
Letters.prototype.each = function(callback){
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(this.letters[i]);
        this.push(callback.call(this, this.letters[i], i));
    }
    return this;
};
```

The test I want to pass is the following:

```
var test = new Letters('dude');
console.log('test1', test); //should return d, u, d, e

var test2 = test.addLetter('x');
console.log('test2', test2); //should return dx, ux, dx, ex

var test3 = test.each(function(e){
   e.addLetter('y');
});
console.log(test3);//should return dxy, uxy, dxy, exy
```

Any ideas on how could I achieve this?
Thanks

Here is a fiddle with the code (open the console to see results): http://jsfiddle.net/cJqqb/

Comment: Do you have any particular programming questions or just expect us to debug (and fix) your code?

Comment: Hi, have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20299788/1636522. I think I've finally figured out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
callback.call(this, this.letters[i], i)
```

...says to call the `callback` function setting its `this` to whatever `this` is in the `.each()` function (which is the instance of `Letter`), and pass `callback` two arguments, `this.letters[i]` and `i` - that is, pass the current item from the array and its index. So far so good, because that's how an each method usually works. But then in your callback:

```
function(e){
   e.addLetter('y');
}
```

...`e` is actually `this.letters[i]` - a string. So `e` has no `.addLetter()` method. That part would "work" in the sense of not giving an error if you changed the callback to be like this:

```
var test3 = test.each(function(){
   this.addLetter('y');
});
```

Though you'd then get an error about your use of `this.push()`, since `this` is an instance of `Letter` and has no `.push()` method. If you remove the `push()` you'd get something that "works" like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cJqqb/1/

But then you'd see that it doesn't make sense to call your existing `.addLetter()` in a loop because `.addLetter()` itself has a loop. You could do this instead to get the expected output:

```
var test3 = test.each(function(v,i){
   this.letters[i] += 'y';
});
```

...but you'll notice that's really not any better than using a `for`loop. The thing is that although your `.each()` implementation passes the value of the current `letters` item to the callback in the first argument you can't actually modify it because it is a string passed by value not by reference, so to actually change the current item you have to access the array it's contained in from which you can set a new value for the element at index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`this.letters` is a collection of `String`s, not `Letters`. So when you call the callback function, the first argument will be a string, not an instance of `Letters`, so `addLetter` isn't defined:

```
var test3 = test.each(function(e){
    e.addLetter('y');  // e is a string! Try this.addLetter('y') instead
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` is a string (one item in the `this.letters` array), that is to say, an instance of the built-in String object, and you're trying to call the `addLetter` method on it, which is obviously going to fail since `String.prototype.addLetter` does not exist. That said, here is my interpretation of your attempts, hope it can help :

```
var Letters = function(word) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, word.split(''));
};

Letters.prototype.each = function (fn) {
    var i = 0, l = this.length;
    for(; i < l; i++) {
        fn.call(this, this[i], i);
    }
    return this;
};

Letters.prototype.addLetter = function(toAdd) {
    this.each(function (item, i) {
        this[i] += toAdd;
    });
    return this;
};

Letters.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return Array.prototype.join.call(this);
};
```

Usage : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/WLt4L/.

Bonus : Here is another demo where Letters inherits from Array : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/kEG56/ (not deeply tested yet).